# UITableViewCell sometimes display a blank

Tags: uitableview

When I refresh the UITableView data, UITableViewCell may be all or part of variable blank sometimes, no matter how I roloadData, the cell no change and display a blank，data sources are no longer call UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate function. this is very low probability events（In most cases, can be normal operation）.

Comment: The code was too much too Arrangement，a few screenshots of run results at ：http://www.eoeandroid.com/thread-542840-1-1.html（I can't upload the picture，sorry）